# Como obtener el id del modal de boostrap que se cerro?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

En una vista tengo varios modales de boostrap y quiero con jquery obtener el id del modal que se cerro ya sea dandole click en el botón de cerrar, en la cruz para cerrar el modal o en una parte fuera del modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias utilizar el evento de cierre del modal y tomar el id y almacenaro ya sea en un input hidden asi podrias utilizarlo cuando lo necesites

```
<input type="hidden" value="" class="closed-modal-id" />

$('#modal, #modal2, #modal3').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  var closedModal = $(this).attr("id");
  $('.closed-modal-id').val(closedModal);
});
```

espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias amigo pero la creación de modales es dinamica y no tengo el subfijo correspondiente al id, aunque es buena la respuesta ya encontré como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede resolver atravez del elemento raiz (document) que contiene todos los elementos y por ende todos los modales verificando cuando se desencadena el evento 'hiden.bs.modal' y pasando ese evento al bloque para verificar el elemento que lo desencadeno y ya solo se obtiene su id con el método attr.

```js
    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
      $(e.target).attr('id');
    })
```

Comment: Considera explicarla por favor, de modo que el resto de la comunidad sepamos que hiciste, revisa [answer]

Comment: Por favor edita tu respuesta y ahí coloca tu explicación